# Run two pieces of code from different programming language in parallel

Tags: java, python

Is there any way to run a function from python and a function from java in one app in parallel and get the result of each function to do another process?

Comment: Your question is not clear, if you want to run python code from java you can do it easily with jython.

Comment: That's what i want, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three ways to achieve that.

a) You could use `java.lang.Runtime` (as in `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`) to launch an external process (from Java side), the external process being your Python script.

b) You could do the same as a), just using Python as launcher.

c) You could use some Python-Java binding, and from Java side use a separate `Thread` to run your Python code.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look for **[jython](https://wiki.python.org/jython/WhyJython)**. This support `Java` and `Python`.